# Topic support when subscribing to Solana programs events

Tags: anchor, solana-program

Anchor events are fairly easy to use in [JS](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/events/tests/events.js) and [Rust](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/events/programs/events/src/lib.rs), nonetheless the current integration many times forces us to receive hundreds or thousands of irrelevant emitted program events. Is there a way to create events with specific topic (for instance a publickey) to enforce uniqueness and improve performance when subscribing to events?